# How to publish a custom story on my feed via my FB App?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I created an app which is in development mode, and I did not submit it for review. I have created a website (on a particular subdomain of mine), which I want to, on certain user actions, publish custom storied on the user's FB feed.

I've created a custom story with verb "Grok" and object "Idea" (fictitious in case you're wondering). Ever since (ok, 2 days), I've tried to make a call to FaceBook's **php** OpenGraph API function `api()` to publish something, but without success.

I've tried many different parameters and parameter combinations (listed below, with the rationale), including FB's own code samples, to no avail. I've also searched the web for tutorials and forum questions about the topic but, to my surprise, did not find much material and certainly no solution to my problem(s).

So how do I, in PHP, publish a custom story to my FB feed ?

Note1: I believe I have the login process right.

Note2: The action Grok has a grey dot that says "not approved", but the errors message I get never mention approval is required

I've read

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/ which does not help much, figured it all out without that.
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph which is great but for iOS, I wish there was such a thing for php
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php which says almost nothing
- [How to correctly publish Open Graph action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547571/how-to-correctly-publish-open-graph-action) not answered the way I wish

---

Now for

- 10 what I've tried
- 20 why
- 30 the error messages I got
- 40 and how I subsequently changed my code
- 50 goto 10

**FB's Sample code for Grok**

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    'me/myapp:grok',
    'POST',
    array('idea' => "http://myapp.mydomain.com/idea?i=".$idea_id)
    );
// handle the response
```

Error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://myapp.mydomain.com/idea?i=1 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'idea' requires an object of og:type 'myapp:idea'. thrown in ...`

At this point I added the following html metatags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="myapp:idea" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Test Title" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="civilizationone" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test Desc" />
```

And got the same error message. So I tried:

**FB's sample code for Idea**

```
$response = $facebook->api('me/objects/myapp:idea',
                           'POST',
                           array('app_id' => 1234567890,
                                 'type' => "idea",
                                 'url' => "http://myapp.mydomain.com.br/idea?i=".$idea_id,
                                 'title' => "test",
                                 'description' => "")
                          );
// handle the response
```

Error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter. thrown in ...`

So I thought the type is `idea` and tried to replace the object by the action:

```
$response = $facebook->api('me/objects/myapp:grok', // Changed here
                           'POST',
                           array('app_id' => 1234567890,
                                 'type' => "idea",
                                 'url' => "http://myapp.mydomain.com.br/idea?i=".$idea_id,
                                 'title' => "test",
                                 'description' => "")
                          );
// handle the response
```

Same error message, so I tried mixing things up:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    'me/objects/myapp:idea',
    'POST',
    array('idea' => "http://myapp.mydomain.com/idea?i=".$idea_id)
    );
```

Error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) The parameter object is required thrown in ...`

Another try:

```
$response = $_SESSION['facebook']->api('me/civilizationone:grok',
                                       'POST',
                                        array('app_id' => 390668467710669,
                                              'type' => "idea",
                                              'url' => "http://myapp.mydomain.com.br/idea?i=".$idea_id,
                                              'title' => "test",
                                              'description' => "",)
                                      );
```

Error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: idea.`

I've tried other combinations that would be tedious to list. So I don't even know which way to go:

- Rely on the HTML metadata and give only the page's URL ?
- Give all the details in the function call so I can remove the metadata ?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, in your "FB's sample code for Idea" example, I think the issue is that you're sending myapp:idea twice, once in myapp:idea and once in the parameters, try changing 'me/objects/myapp:idea' to just 'me' any luck?

Comment: @Crawdingle I actually get no exception but a return code 1 ! I suspect this is an advance...

Comment: But I get nothing on FB. The app is in test mode so my contacts should not see the publication, but I guess I should. Besides, where do I put the verb ?